# What does "whole site" mean in "X is a whole site meaner than Y"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In *Sling Blade (1996)*, Karl speaks about drunken Doyle:

> Karl: That feller's a **whole site** meaner than me.
> He'd just whup the tar out of me.

What does "whole site" mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think either you or the author has misspelled *sight*:
[Merriam-Webster *sight*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sight)

> noun  a : chiefly dialectal
> a : **a great number or quantity**
> b : **a good deal : lot**
> *a far sight better*,   *not by a damn sight*

[AHD *sight*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=sight)

> Idioms:
> a sight (Upper Southern US)
> **A lot; much:**
> *We're a sight better off without him.*

[emphasis added]

So, your example should be spelled *a whole sight meaner*, and it means *much meaner*.

Comment: We can say 'a damn sight' in Britain.

Comment: For what it's worth, just checking the first 2 Google results: [Daily Script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/sling_blade.html) has "sight", but [Script-o-Rama](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/s/sling-blade-script-transcript-billy.html) has "site".  No idea which (if either) is closer to "official".

Comment: The whole line as presented is in [eye dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect), so just as "feller" and "whup" are used instead of more standard equivalents, "site" doesn't look out of place.

Comment: @ChrisDown In the cases of *feller* and *whup* for *fellow* and *whip*,  dialectal pronunciations are represented. I can't imagine a pronunciation difference between *site* and *sight* that would justify this misspelling.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty There *might* be a slight difference in the length of the vowel, but I can't see it being noticeable to a native english speaker.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty At least to me as a northern BrE speaker, I hear a difference in vowel length between "site" and "sight".